# Cannot get button click to toggle class

Tags: javascript, html, css

No matter what I try to do, I cannot get classes to toggle on a button click. I have tried many different ways and no matter what I do I cannot get it to work. I think I am making a very simple mistake but I haven't been able to figure it out. I am trying to figure this out so that I can build a navigation that goes in and out of view after you click a button.

```js
document.querySelector("btn-toggle").addEventListener("click",
  function() {
    document.getElementById("myDIV").classList.toggle("style");
  });
```

```css
.style {
  background: green;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-toggle">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
  This is a DIV element.
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

`.btn-toggle` is the class name of the `button`, so you need to select the class appropriately - with `querySelector`, that would be `".btn-toggle"`. (The `.` in front indicates to search for a *class* with that name)

```js
document.querySelector(".btn-toggle").addEventListener("click",
  function() {
    document.getElementById("myDIV").classList.toggle("style");
  });
```

```css
.style {
  background: green;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-toggle">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
  This is a DIV element.
</div>
```

Using `querySelector("btn-toggle")` indicates that you're searching for an element whose *tag name* is `btn-toggle`, which is not what you want.

Comment: Beat me to it. 

Answer (score 0):

You should add a dot to your selector to make it a class selector.

For example ".btn-toggle" would match your button. With code you have shown us querySelector will search for a tag named btn-toggle.

Comment: That was the fix, simple mistake. Thanks!